# What is the difference between 'remind someone of' and 'remind someone about'?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference between 'remind someone of' and 'remind someone about'?

Some examples:

> Let me remind you of the document you signed several weeks ago.
>
> You asked me to remind you about the Earl of Rochester.
>
> It reminded Meg of the Cheshire Can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, the use of the word "of" means the subject is being directly compared to what is being remembered.

> The overly-large grin on the smiley face picture reminded Meg of the Cheshire Cat.

The Cheshire Cat is known to have an overly-large grin, which is why it triggered Meg to think of the Cheshire Cat.

The use of the word "about" just directly refers to something, and there is no comparison taking place.

> Thank you for reminding me about my appointment tomorrow morning.